# Put the right man "on the right job" or "in the right job"?

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english

I googled and found some examples with "in". But when I asked my native friend, he told me it should be "on".

Comment: Depends on the context/meaning.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, *on the job* refers to a task assignment, while *in the job* refers to a job slot placement.
You choose the one that means what you intend.
It might be different in Britain.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct, but the meanings can be quite different:

- "That looks difficult." ...

"Yes, we'll put that young Einstein chap on this job."

vs

- "Rimmer's struggling when it comes to avoiding asteroids. It's a good thing the deflector shields are working." ...

"Yes; do you think the skipper's put him in the right job?"

The first has 'job' = 'task', the second 'job' = 'post'.

From [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/job):

> **job** [A2]
>
> a particular piece of work:
>
> - *The builders are aiming to get the job done by the end of the month.*
> - [*When I am working on a job I bear in mind that I am being paid for an assignment that an editor needs.*][[Linguee.com](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/translation/work+on+a+job.html)]
>   .................
>
> **job** [A1]
>
> the regular work that a person does to earn money:
>
> - *When she left college, she got a job as an editor in a publishing company.*
> - *It's very difficult trying to bring up two children while doing a full-time job.*
> - [*Good employees don't want to work in a job where they're not trusted by leadership.*] [[kununu](https://b2b.kununu.com/blog/why-do-good-employees-quit-leave-their-job)]